# FLTK, error: language objective-c++ not recognized

Tags: gcc, g++, objective-c++

Trying to compile [`fltk`](http://www.fltk.org/index.php) in Mac OSX.

Have just upgraded to gcc 6.2

Getting error:

> g++: error: language objective-c++ not recognized

Does anyone know how to fix?